# Fancybox 2 scrollbar disapears and site shifts to the right

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a small issue with fancybox 2. I'm now to the coding stuff so sorry if I am going to ask stupid questions.

I got the fancybox working on the testsite but when I click on an image the box opens and the whole page in the background shifts to the right and the scrollbar disappears. I don't want this behaviour. The scrollbar should be there.

It is on this site: http://elgaucho.lu/restaurant.php

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: In order for people to help you they will need to see your code. You can edit your question to include your source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you modified the original fancybox css file.

You changed the line 167 from this

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

into this

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right:0 !important;
}
```

... and the line 187 from this

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

into this

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

... so no wonders (bear in mind that the js file also changes some css properties dynamically so you may not have full control just changing the css file)

Generally speaking you shouldn't mess with the original files unless you are pretty sure what you are doing, otherwise you will have unexpected results

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. These changes were my try to follow some suggestions in forums to solve the problem I have. now the original file is in place but the scrollbar is gone when I'm clicking on an image :(

Comment: if you want to have the page scroll bars (so you can scroll the page on the background of fancybox) then add this API option `helpers : { overlay : { locked  : false } }`

Comment: Thanks :-) This solved my problem. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by adding the following code in the main CSS file:

```
body { margin: 0 !important; }
.fancybox-lock,
.fancybox-overlay { overflow: visible !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue... scrollbar disappeared and page shifted to the right. Annoying, but this code indeed works. Just add it to any of your fancybox css file (or any included css file for that matter).

```
.fancybox-lock, .fancybox-overlay { overflow: visible !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the page to always scroll with:

```
body {overflow-y: auto !important;}
```

Comment: Him Thanks for your help. But when I add this line to the fancybox css file i'm having two scroll bars at the right...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my solution was easier than I expected it to be. I simply went into the html  and noticed I'd had two body's

In the code (near the bottom) there is the following:

```
    body {
        max-width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

I deleted that and my website now went back to being centred.

Comment: Is this code for your site or for the question's site?

Answer (score 0):

**added:**

.fancybox-lock, .fancybox-overlay { overflow: visible !important;}
body {overflow: visible !important;}

**removed:**

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;}

***fine***